# Mongoose bcrypt set password and saving asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await, bcrypt

I have a mongoose schema:

```
UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds).then(function (hash) {
    this.hash = hash;
    }); 
};
```

and here is how I create the user object:

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
var user = new User();

user.username = req.body.user.username;
user.email = req.body.user.email;
user.setPassword(req.body.user.password);

user.save().then(function(){
  return res.json({user: user.toAuthJSON()});
    }).catch(next);
});
```

However, it saves the user without the hashed password. I guess it's because the bcrypt.hash callback didn't run before user.save is called. How can I best resolve this issue?

On the bcrypt doc it says not to use bcrypt.hashSync, would it be an appropriate here?

Comment: try put an arrow function in the then so this will refer to the mongos schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (error, hash) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            this.password = hash;
            resolve(true);
        }
    })
  })
}
```

and then call

```
await user.setPassword(req.body.user.password);
```

or maybe catch the error, idk